# Python - extract an elliptic curve private key from pem file

Tags: python, elliptic-curve, pyopenssl

How do I extract an elliptic curve private key from a pem file to use for signing data in python?

I have been using pyOpenSSL to load the private key, but don't understand the process of extracting the elliptic curve.

Comment: What form do you want the private key?